# composition of differentiable functions over manifolds

Tags: calculus, manifolds

> Let $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m,N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ manifolds and $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^n,g:N\to\mathbb{R}^d$ differentiable functions and $f(M)\subset N$ prove $g\circ f$ is differentiable

My attempt is maybe taking charts  that exist because $f,g$ are differentiable and try to compose all of them together but not sure it's the right way.

I'm new to manifolds so help will be welcome :)

Comment: Yes, your strategy is good.